# How to prevent JAX-WS from putting package as a default namespace into elements when it should be empty?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm using wsimport as follows:

```
wsimport -keep -s src -p "ru.company.test" -Xnocompile -b jaxbFile.xjb StandartSvc.xsd
```

In WSDL, there are an empty targetNamespace:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="StandartSvc"
targetNamespace="">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"> ...
```

But in the resulting SOAP queries (trying to invoke method GetShortOrganizationInfo), there is namespace "http://test.company.ru":

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <ns13:GetShortOrganizationInfo
        xmlns:ns10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
        xmlns:ns11="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CorpGuard.Common"
        xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Casebook.Search.Common.Arbitr.Enums"
        xmlns:ns13="http://test.company.ru/"
        xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FnsUtils.Gate2FNSService.ULFounders"
        xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FnsUtils.Gate2FNSService.Model"
        xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CorpGuard.BL.DataObjects"
        xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BaseService.Models"
        xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Casebook.Common"
        xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
        xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Parcsis.Common.Data"
        xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FnsUtils.Gate2FNSService.UlFounders">
        <inn />
        <ogrn />
        <name>XXX</name>
        <address />
    </ns13:GetShortOrganizationInfo>
</S:Body>
```

The only thing that helps is to use wsimport with empty package argument:

```
wsimport -keep -s src -p "" -Xnocompile -b jaxbFile.xjb StandartSvc.xsd
```

But default package isn't ok for me.

Tried to force namespace = "" in generated sources (into @XmlType and @XmlRootElement annotations):

```
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"inn",
"ogrn",
"name",
"address"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetShortOrganizationInfo")
public class GetShortOrganizationInfo { ...
```

but that didn't help. Also, tried to create package-info.java:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "")
package ru.company.test;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

didn't help as well. Any ideas how to prevent JAX-WS/JAXB from using package as namespace and leave it empty?

Comment: Why don't you specify a namespace in your WSDL ?
Empty namespace is a bad practice in the XML word.

Comment: It would be great, but it isn't my service, I have to interact with it as it is (